# SQLAlchemy with_polymorhpic and mixins

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, polymorphism, mixins

I have the following class hierarchy (using SQLAlchemy with declarative base):

```
class Item(DeclarativeBase):
    name = Column(String(30))


class DetailsMixin(object):
    details = Column(String(300))

class AItem(Item):
    ...

class BItem(Item, DetailsMixin):
    ...

class CItem(Item, DetailsMixin):
    ...

class Something(DeclarativeBase, DetailsMixin)
    ...
```

Is it possible to use `with_polymorhpic` to get all Items and load `details` column if present, but without explicitly naming the names of classes that inherit `DetailsMixin`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQLalchemy Joined Inheritance Query Based on Mixin Column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22262098/sqlalchemy-joined-inheritance-query-based-on-mixin-column)

Answer (score 0):

```
with_polymorphic(base = Item, classes = '*')
```

Will load all classes that inherit from `Item`, at least that are visible when the `__mapper__` arguments are evaluated. So the classes that inherit your mixins will be loaded as their actual class, and thus have their mixed-in column.

If you're asking how to do *queries* based on that mixin column without having to explicitly name the classes that inherit from `DetailsMixin`, that's something I'm still trying to figure out myself. But clarifying your question would probably help with answers.

Comment: I was asking about the second thing. I figured it out myself. I'll write an answer here in a minute.

Comment: Cool, can you post your answer in my [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22262098/sqlalchemy-joined-inheritance-query-based-on-mixin-column/22263533?noredirect=1#22263533) as well?